# ggplot2 - Swimmers Plot color coding

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on swimmers plot for a set of data. I am trying to color code each bar based on whether or not the patient is still on treatment. What is the correct function to add a legend and this color coding based on if the patient is on treatment or not?

Example data frame TonT1:

> ```
> Patient ID        Time1(months)     On Treatment (1 for yes, 0 for no)
> 1                     6                    1
> 2                     4.7                  0
> 3                     2.3                  1
> 4                     9.7                  1
> ```

... etc.

My code is below:

```
ggplot(data=TonT1, aes(x=reorder(Patient.ID, Time1), y=Time1)) + ylim(0,15) + ylab("Time on Therapy") + xlab("Patient ID") + theme_classic() + geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.5, fill = "steelblue")
```

Comment: Inside `aes()`, add in `fill = factor(On.Treatment)`. The legend will be automatically added. (Judging by the discrepancy in your column names from example data to example code, `Patient ID` vs `Patient.ID`, I'm assuming the actual column name is `On.Treatment`)

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to add arrows as well?

Comment: Not with `geom_bar`, but `geom_segment` has them. Just search for it: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bggplot2%5D+arrows

Comment: Thanks! the fill = factor ran with no errors but didn't change the color.  Is it ok for it to be binary?

Comment: Sorry, didn't scroll. You need to delete `fill = "steelblue"` in `geom_bar`, that overrides the mapped fill to always use that one color. (Maybe edit your question to include line breaks in the code so horizontal scrolling isn't necessary.)